# Centrar columnas dinamicamente

Tags: html, css

estoy realizando una web en la cual necesito centrar dinamicamente unas columnas, cada columna se llena con valores que consumo desde un backend, es decir que si existe un solo elemento este debe apacer en el centro de la vista, así mismo si existen dos elementos estos deben aparecer centrados, el limite de columnas a mostrar son 4.

```
 <div class="chefs col-md-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12" style="width: 100%;">
  <div class="row list_chefs">
   <div class="Tchef col" *ngFor="let item of datosChef">
    <div>
     <img src="{{item.photo}}" alt="" class="img_Tchef">
    </div>
     <p class="nombre_Tchef">{{item.surname}} {{item.last_name}}</p>
     <div class="row cont_bHats">
       <div *ngFor="let sombrero of item.rateArray" class="black_hats">
        <img class="img_black_h" src="{{sombrero.icon}}">
       </div>
      </div>
      <button class="btn-seleccionar" (click)="sendchef(item)">SELECCIONAR</button>
     </div>

    </div>

   </div>
```

Como puedo centrar esa columna para que cuando salgan de 1 a 3 elementos aparezca al centro.

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres solo mostrar elementos centrados verticalmente puedes usar en el padre el siguiente css:

```
.padre_contenedor{
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Ejemplo:

```css
*{
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 1px;
}

.father_container{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1em;
  min-height: 10em;
}

.father_container p{
  padding: .5em;
}
```

```html
<div class="father_container">

  <p> contenido </p>
  <p> contenido asdasd</p>
  <p> contenido </p>
  <p> contenidoasd aasdsad </p>
  <p> contenido </p>

</div>
```